# Servlet Spring + jax rs services

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I`m new in spring services and I'm trying to create a simple Web service example with returns String Hello Wolrd. My code configuration is:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServletName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.MyPackageDirectionWebServices.remoting</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</servlet-mapping>
```

HelloWs.java

```
package com.MyPackageDirectionWebServices.remoting;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller

@RequestMapping("/hello")

public class HelloWs {
    @RequestMapping(value= "helloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody

    public String HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

And in my AppContext-Remoting.xml I added teh follow anotation.

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.MyPackageDirectionServices.remoting" />
```

But when I start my App and I go to the service:

```
localhost:8080/MyAppname/rest/hello/helloWorld
```

I get the HTTP 404- and found this error in Eclipse console:

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MyAppname/rest/hello/helloWorld] in DispatcherServlet with name 'MyServletName

Can somebody help me whith this? Thnaks a lot!

Comment: Try adding a slash: `@value = '/helloHworld'`.

Comment: Thanks but I tried with the slash and the result was the same. Some more ideas?

Comment: Spring recognizes the clases @controller because the console says:

Comment: where did you mention that 'AppContext-Remoting.xml' is your configuration file?

Comment: It's the configuration file of spring in src/main/resources. I'm not sure that I must create a servlet.xml under my WEBINF folder, and mention it on <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name> ? It's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toni, you need to mention the spring config xml file name in contextConfigLocation like below(change path according to your need).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/AppContext-Remoting.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

If you have java configuration (instead of xml file), you can use contextClass and contextConfigLocation in different way;